# A way of stripping everything before and after ' or " (including the quotes themselves)

Tags: python

I am trying to find a means to strip everything before or after either single or double quotes, including the quotes themselves.

For example:

```
<script src = "https://example.com/file.js"></script>
```

Result:

```
https://example.com/file.js
```

Or:

```
url = 'https://example.com/service/api'
```

Result:

```
https://example.com/service/api
```

I have tried using `.strip` and `.replace` , as well as the `re` library, but I am grasping in the dark here.

Using an HTML parsing library is no good here, because we don't know in advance in which language the code is. We are searching through lines of text looking for URL's to then send the URL itself to another API. This could be in text files, yaml, json, java, c#, python, ruby, etc.

Comment: Apologies for messing up the title (I somehow missed the word "remove")

Comment: @Chris_Rands split can remove the quotes, its the strings outside of that (see first example <script...)

Comment: You probably want a proper HTML parser that will return the `src` attribute of a `script` element, rather than messing with the raw text.

Comment: what about `"asd's"` or `"asd\"s"` ? ... this is not such an easy problem ... what about `"hello 'awesome' world "`? if it was a python program you could use ast to get all the string nodes

Comment: @chepner - that will work for html formatted strings using known delimiters - but this could be anything at all that is not using html tags {"http:..}

Comment: @JoranBeasley this is python.

Comment: @devnull maybe you could come up with a parser using something like ply ... but its not going to be easy

Comment: @devnull thats html python looks like `a_var = "a string"`

Comment: @devnull Then clearly, you have two different problems. Treating HTML (or anything structured) as raw text is rarely the correct solution.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I see what you mean now, I thought you meant by python the language I am using, but you mean as the possible strings I need to parse.

Comment: @chepner , understood..the problem is the language needed to be parsed is an unknown, we are searching through lines of code looking for URL's to then send the URL itself to another API. This could be in text files, yaml, json, java, c#, python, ruby etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to remove everything prior and after the target string, you can think of it as extracting the target string and not its surrounding context.

Extract the quoted string using regex match groups:

```
import re
string = '<script src = "https://example.com/file.js"></script>'
match = re.search("(\".+?\"|'.+?')", string)
target = match.group(1).strip("\"'")
```

`target` is equal to `https://example.com/file.js`.
The regex in `re.search()` matches either `"somestring"` or `'somestring'`. The contents of the group between parentheses can be extracted using `match.group(1)`. We then remove the quotes on either side using `strip()`.

You might want to use something like

```
if match:
    target = match.group(1).strip("\"'")
```

because `match` will be `None` if the regex doesn't match anything.

Comment: There is a way to have the regex match only what is between quotes and extract that directly, but I didn't find a way to make that regex not awful.